# How do I use cxml-stp's find-recursively and find-recursively-if

Tags: xml, lisp, common-lisp

I couldn't find examples and can't figure out the documentation for these functions:

- [`find-recursively`](http://www.lichteblau.com/cxml-stp/doc/pages/cxml-stp__fun__find-recursively.html)
- [`find-recursively-if`](http://www.lichteblau.com/cxml-stp/doc/pages/cxml-stp__fun__find-recursively-if.html)

Say I want to find the first `<div class="summary">` on the front page of Stack Overflow.  I can get the HTML tree this way:

```lisp
(defun get-page (url)
  "Get STP(DOM alternative) representation of page"
  (chtml:parse
   (drakma:http-request url)
   (cxml-stp:make-builder)))

(get-page "http://stackoverflow.com")
```

From here, though, I just don't know what `find-recursively` and `find-recursively-if` should look like with real arguments.

Edit: Solution to finding first `<div class="summary">` on the front page of SO using `find-recursively-if`:

```lisp
(cxml-stp:find-recursively-if
 (lambda (node)
   (and (typep node 'cxml-stp:element)
    (equal (stp:local-name node) "div")
    (equal (stp:attribute-value node "class") "summary")))
 (get-page "http://stackoverflow.com"))
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like to do?  It looks like these functions work pretty much the same way that CL's `find` and `find-if` work.  `item` could be a node, in which case you'd find the node directly, or could be, e.g., a number, if the `key` function takes a node and returns a number, etc.…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions walk the node tree and return when you find the desired node (in the case of `find-recursively`) or a node satisfying the predicate (in the case of `find-recursively-if`).  The predicate should probably do something with the node, but could be arbitrary.  E.g., here's a way to return the 10th node (by using a predicate that will return true on its 10th invocation):

```lisp
;; return the 10th node
(let ((x 0))
  (cxml-stp:find-recursively-if 
   (lambda (node)
     (= (incf x) 10))
   (get-page "http://stackoverflow.com")))
```

As a more realistic example, here's how you could retrieve an element with the local name `"title"` (note that you can only use `local-name` on `elements`, and not on arbitrary `node`s, so the `:key` function is a little awkward):

```lisp
CL-USER> (cxml-stp:find-recursively
          "title"
          (get-page "http://stackoverflow.com")
          :key (lambda (node)
                 (if (typep node 'cxml-stp:element)
                     (cxml-stp:local-name node)
                     ""))
          :test 'string-equal)
;=>
;#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
;   #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
;   :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:TEXT
;                  #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
;                  :DATA "Stack Overflow"))
;   :LOCAL-NAME "title"
;   :NAMESPACE-URI "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
```